# Can circuit without memory give output depending on the order in which input pins were activated for non-commutative operations?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, boolean-algebra, alu, nand

Going trough making small NAND based computer.

I have two input pins **zy** (zero 16 bit Array y),  **ny** (negate bitwise 16 bit Array y).
Implementing each one separately or in connection is no problem but there is a difference in output that depends on order of activation - because these operations are not commutative.

My ALU is made without flip-flops etc. no memory elements so can it still distinguish between order of inputs without them, using only 1 pin per operation? I feel that no because once two pins are active circuit can't distinguish in which order they were activated. Is it so? How that problem is addressed in real circuits? Do you need (log n)2 pins for describing all permutations of non-commutative operations in your circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purely combinatorial circuit, i.e. one without ANY feedback, when it settles after an input change, will have an output that depends only on the inputs, and not on the history of the inputs.

However, if even a single feedback line is added to a combinatorial circuit, i.e. some output is fed back into an input, then the circuit will (or at leas *can*) have memory. Explicit memory elements, such as flip-flops are not needed. All that is required for the outputs to depend upon the history of inputs is one or more feedback lines.

Answer (score 1):

If it really has no memory elements -- neither explicit nor implicit ones -- then no, it cannot remember the order of events.

A system has memory if and only if its present behavior is influenced by previous inputs (i.e., because it *remembers* what happened).  Note the "if and only if" -- this works both ways.  So a system whose present behavior is influenced by past inputs, **by definition** has memory, whether you put it in there on purpose or not.